# How to map host path with service path in ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

How to create an alb ingress such that only "/" will redirect to a service that shows static files in service-1. all other paths should redirect to service 2. it will host something like this

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: a.abc.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /v1
            backend:
              serviceName: service-2/v1
              servicePort: 9090
```

I know I can't have `service-2/v1` on `serviceName` but I want to map `/v1` to `service-2:9090/v1`.

I am hosting some static files in `service-1(nginx)` which I want to show on `/` and then `/v1` and `/admin` is on my another service (i.e `service-2/v1` and `service-2/admin`).

Comment: Typically, an ingress controller wont strip that path by default. So, for example, if you used Kong or nginx, the above Ingress definition should work fine if you remove `/v1` from `serviceName: service-2/v1`.

Answer (score 1):

Name of the service and any other resource may not contain `/` and `%` as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#path-segment-names) and if you would like to deploy it, it will show following error:

`metadata.name: Invalid value: "demo/v1": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')`

So you have to consider changing name of the services, besides that you can specify multiple paths in single `Ingress` definition:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: a.abc.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /v1
            backend:
              serviceName: service-v1
              servicePort: 9090
          - path: /admin #additional path
            backend:
              serviceName: service-admin   #service name pointing to /admin
              servicePort: 9091    #port it will be accessible on
```